# Buscando dados a partir de uma ID na DB

Tags: php, sql, banco-de-dados, query

Dei uma pesquisada aqui e no google para ver se resolveria meu problema sem ter que fazer uma pergunta, mas não consegui encontrar nenhuma solução.

O que estou tentando fazer é criar um "relacionados" mas sem que exibe o mesmo post ou vídeo no caso. No caso estou usando o seguinte código:

```
<?php
    if(!@mysql_connect("localhost","root",""))
    {
        die('oops connection problem ! --> '.mysql_error());
    }
    if(!mysql_select_db("player"))
    {
        die('oops database selection problem ! --> '.mysql_error());
    }
    $query = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM videopv2 WHERE `videopv2`.`tipo_relacao`= '$tipode' ORDER BY id DESC");
    while ($relacionados = @mysql_fetch_object($query)):
        ?>
    <article class="video-preview <?php echo $relacionados->categoria_video; ?>" data-viewkey="6b684234a3" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
        <a title="<?php echo $relacionados->titulo_video; ?>" itemprop="url" target="_blank" href="/AP/embed/<?php echo $relacionados->id; ?>">
            <img class="media-preview-thumbnail js-resrc js-resrc-lazy" alt="<?php echo $relacionados->titulo_video ?>" itemprop="thumbnailUrl" src="/AP/assets/embed/imgs/<?php echo $relacionados->imagem_video; ?>" data-src="/AP/assets/embed/imgs/<?php echo $relacionados->imagem_video; ?>" />
            <h4 class="media-preview-title" itemprop="name"><?php echo $relacionados->titulo_video; ?></h4>
        </a>
    </article>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Não ficou claro pra mim a descrição do problema.Importante resaltar que as funções mysql_* estão obsoletas.

Comment: @MarcosXavier, por exemplo, estou acessando uma postagem, e no rodapé tem uma parte onde exibi as postagens relacionadas. Nesse campo, eu queria saber como que faço para buscar sem que apareça a mesma postagem(que está aberta na página). Em questão do mysql_* qual é o método que está sendo utilizado agora?, estou aprendendo php com algumas video aulas antigas.

Comment: Utilize Pdo ao invés de mysql_*. 
Sobre a query, você poderia armazenar o id da postagem exibida em um variável e fazer algo tipo "select * table where idPostagem != idPostagemAberta"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para teu código funcionar vamos fazer algumas alterações. Mas primeiro vamos a teoria.

Você está utilizando a forma procedural do mysqli_query e está pulando algumas etapas. Caso queira saber mais, existe a forma orientado a objetos do mysqli::query. Abordei as diferenças de como utilizá-los [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220978/banco-de-dados-n%C3%A3o-funciona/220997#220997).

Criei um arquivo de conexão ao banco separado. Assim centraliza a conexão ao banco em apenas um lugar do seu projeto e evita retrabalhos.

```
include "conexao.php";
```

Como você não postou nada de como está sendo feito a conexão, vou colocar como é feito na forma procedural: (Não que o seu esteja errado)

```
// Conecta ao banco de dados
mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'usuario', 'senha');
mysql_select_db('banco');
```

Dica: após conectar o banco verifique se não houve erros:

```
/* valida conexão ao banco */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Falha na conexão ao banco: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

Para realizar uma consulta com base em uma query você pode fazer assim:

```
// Monta e executa uma consulta SQL
$sql = "SELECT *` FROM `usuarios`";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
```

Para percorrer a consulta você pode fazer usando um laço de repetição, exatamente como está fazendo:

```
// Para cada resultado encontrado...
while ($usuario = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  // Exibe um link com a notícia
  echo $usuario['nome'] . ' - ' . $usuario['email'];
} // fim while
```

Repare que no array $usuario['nome'] é aspas simples (''), ao invés de crases (``).

E uma dica para exibir o total de linhas vindas na consulta

```
// Total de notícias
echo 'Total de notícias: ' . mysql_num_rows($query);
```

Qualquer dúvida basta comentar.