# Banco de dados não funciona

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, formulário, phpmyadmin

Nunca fiz um formulário, então, perdoem se estiver absurdamente errado.

Aqui está o banco com a tabela:

```
CREATE DATABASE db_formacao;
USE db_formacao;

CREATE TABLE  `db_formacao`.`formacoes` (
`ID` INT( 5 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`NOME` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
`OBJETIVO` TEXT NOT NULL ,
`CARGA` INT( 5 ) NOT NULL ,
`CONTEUDO` TEXT NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (  `ID` )
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

Já aqui, na própria página que o formulário está sendo construído tento fazer a conexão:

```
<?php
    $conn = new mysqli ("localhost", "root", "", "db_formacoes");

    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $objetivo = $_POST['objetivo'];
    $conteudo = $_POST['conteudo'];
    $carga = $_POST['carga'];

    $squery = "INSERT INTO formacoes (nome, objetivo, conteudo, carga) VALUES('$nome','$objetivo','$conteudo', '$carga' )";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conn,$squery);


    if(!mysqli_query($conn, $squery)){  
        echo 'Opa! Não conseguimos nos conectar ao banco de dados. '. mysqli_error($conn);
    }else{
        echo 'Operação realizada com sucesso';
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Quando clico no botão de salvar do formulário nada acontece para indicar que foram ou não salvas as informações e estou verificando isso fazendo um select no phpMyAdmin. Segue o resultado encontrado: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Antes de começar, você nomeou o banco de dados como `db_formacao` mas utilizou `use formacao`, sem o prefixo `db_`. Isto está correto? A função [`mysqli_connect`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysqli-connect.php) recebe quatro parâmetros, incluindo caminho do servidor, usuário, senha e nome do banco. Você passou apenas o primeiro. E você também não concatenou corretamente os valores em `$sql`.

Comment: Opa, não sei. Deixa eu mudar e ver se funciona.

Comment: Tem certeza que conecta mesmo? Ali no mysqli_connect falta passar o login, pass e nome do banco

Comment: falta definir a database, login, e senha, e o nome da tabela criada foi `formacoes` na query você utilizou `db_formacao`

Comment: @MarianaFerreira existem diversos erros na pergunta, um deles o @AndersonCarlosWoss já comentou. Outra coisa: lá no INSERT INTO, você está usando `db_formacao` ao invés de `db_formacao.formacoes` e logo em seguida, você faz `$sql = ` ao invés de fazer `$sql .= ` para concatenar as `strings`.

Comment: Então, o banco não tem uma senha.

Comment: Sim mas mesmo não tendo uma senha tem o login root e no lugar da senha coloque ""

Comment: Você pode editar a pergunta pra eu ver como exatamente eu deveria mudar meu código?

Comment: Vou editar o código para as alterações que eu fiz.

Comment: Otimo está melhorando,duvida você está recebendo os dados no post? ja deu um echo para ver? ali onde tem o $sql você pode colocar junto não é necessário separar, fazendo com que fique assim $sql = "INSERT INTO db_formacao.formacoes(NOME,OBJETIVO,CARGA,CONTEUDO) VALUES ('{$NOME}', '{$OBJETIVO}', '{$CARGA}' ,'{$CONTEUDO}')"; Essas chaves são para determinar que é uma variavel

Comment: @MarianaFerreira vi que editou o código da pergunta, mas não editou os textos. Tem como descrever o que está acontecendo agora quando executa este código? Aparece algum erro? O registro é cadastrado?

Comment: Então, não aparece nada que confirme que foi ou não cadastrado o formulário. Estou verificando fazendo um select na tabela pelo phpMyAdmin, mas diz que a tabela está vazia, então, não foi cadastrado.

Comment: @MarianaFerreira Recomendo fortemente você ler [Como gravar valores no banco de dados MYSQL usando PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219812/5878)

Comment: @MarianaFerreira Conseguiu? Por favor faça as alterações que pedi caso não coseguiu e me desculpe esqueci de colocar o nome do banco  nessa linha mysqli_connect('localhost', "root", "",db_formacao)

Comment: Fiz as alterações que sugeriu e infelizmente ainda não funciona. Estou lendo o link enviado no comentário anterior. Obrigada. :)

Comment: Então, a mensagem que eu tinha deixado para aparecer caso desse erro na conexão com o banco de dados aparece assim que eu entro na minha página do formulário, antes mesmo de eu tentar cadastrar algo. Ou seja, por algum motivo o banco não se conecta.

Comment: @AndersonHenrique

Comment: Poderia disponibilizar o código de como está ? @MarianaFerreira

Comment: Sim, vou editar

Answer (score 2):

Para conectar o banco usando `mysqli_query`, segundo a documentação do [PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.query.php), existe duas formas:

- Procedural: `mysql_query`
- Orientado a Objetos: `mysqli_query`

> Obs.: Somente no estilo procedural utiliza o recurso retornado por [mysqli_connect()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysqli-connect.php) ou [mysqli_init()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.init.php)

Para conectar estilo procedural:

```
$con = mysql_connect('host', 'usuario', 'senha')
or die('Erro ao conectar: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('banco') or die('Banco não encontrado');

/* Realiza um *SELECT* no banco */
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `usuario` LIMIT 5";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Erro no SQL: ' . mysql_error());

//Exibe os dados
echo "<table>\n";
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "\t<tr>\n";
    foreach ($line as $col_value) {
        echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
    }
    echo "\t</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";

// Libera um resultado da memória
mysql_free_result($result);

// Fecha conexão
mysql_close($result);
```

Para conectar o banco usando o estilo orientado à objeto:

```
$con = new mysqli('host', 'usuario', 'senha', 'banco');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Falha na conexão ao banco: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `usuario` LIMIT 5";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if ($query) {
    // Pode fazer assim
    while ($usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        // Exibe um link com a notícia
        echo $usuario['nome'] . ' - ' . $usuario['email'];
        echo '<br/>';
    } // fim while

    // Ou assim
    while ($usuario = mysqli_fetch_object($query)) {
        // Exibe um link com a notícia
        echo $usuario->nome . ' - ' . $usuario->email;
        echo '<br/>';
    }
} 

echo 'Total de notícias: ' . mysqli_num_rows($query);
```

- [mysqli_fetch_assoc](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php): Obtem uma linha do conjunto de resultados como uma matriz associativa
- [mysqli_fetch_object](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php): Retorna a linha atual do conjunto de resultados como um objeto

[Aqui](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/usando-o-mysqli-orientado-a-objetos) há um tutorial de como realizar consultas usando, tanto a forma procedural, quanto orientado a objetos. Qualquer dúvida só comentar na resposta.

Comment: +1 Dijalma, boa resposta!

Comment: Desculpe se essa pergunta foi muito leiga, mas aí seria só a conexão e, na página do formulário, teria que fazer aquele php criando as variáveis que recebem as informações do formulário pra enviar pro banco?

Comment: @Mariana, sim. No `form` você aponta para o aquivo `php` através do `action="processa_form.php"`. Se você escolher o `method="POST"`, no `php` você irá capturar as informações assim: `$nome = $_POST['nome']`.

Comment: Tipo o que eu fiz aí na questão?

Comment: Exatamente. Uma sugestão. Separe a conexão do banco em arquivo separado e adicione através do `include="conexao.php"`.