# Buscando dados no banco de dados

Tags: php, sql, banco-de-dados

Boa noite, estou com dúvida em um certo código.
Ele deve buscar todos os usuários no banco de dados e listar... porem da erro...[image: Como pode ser visto aqui]

Segue o trecho do código onde faço as instruções para o mesmo buscar os dados:

```
<?php
session_start();
include "seguranca.php";
include "conexao.php";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="Painel Administrativo">
    <meta name="author" content="Prisma Design">
    <link rel="icon" href="imagens/favicon.ico">

    <title>Painel Administrativo</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="administrativo.php">Painel Administrativo 0.1 BETA</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Painel</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Configurações</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Perfil</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ajuda</a></li>
          </ul>
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Procurar...">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
          <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
            <li><a href="administrativo.php">Vista geral</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Suporte</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
            <li><a href="adiciona_user.php">Adicionar usuário</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="lista_user.php">Listar usuários <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
            <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
          <h3 class="page-header"><?php echo "Bem vindo:  ".$_SESSION['usuarioNome']; ?></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
          <table class="table table-hover">
            <tr>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>E-mail</th>
            <th>Usuário</th>
            <th>Nível</th>
            </tr>
            <?
              $lista = mysqli_connect($conectar, "SELECT * FROM `usuario`");
              while($escrever=mysql_fetch_array($lista)){
                echo “<tr><td>” . $escrever[’nome’] . “</td><td>” . $escrever[’email’] . “</td><td>” . $escrever[’usuario’] . “</td><td>” . $escrever[’nivel_acesso_id’] . “</td></tr>”;

              }
                echo “</table>”;
                </table>
                mysql_close(conexao);

            ?>
            <tr>

          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

EDIT!

Fiz o que vocês me falaram, agora ta dando esse erro aqui:

[image: foto do erro]

Comment: o erro está sendo no php, linha 80 conforme mostra o print, um caractere inesperado '<' verifique essa linha ou poste o php completo

Comment: a linha 80:                 echo “<tr><td>” . $escrever[’nome’] . “</td><td>” . $escrever[’email’] . “</td><td>” . $escrever[’usuario’] . “</td><td>” . $escrever[’nivel_acesso_id’] . “</td><tr>”;

Comment: a última tag, você não está fechando a `<tr>`, tem que ficar `</tr>` apesar que isso parece ser um erro html, e não do php. Você pode editar a pergunta para colocar o código completo.

Comment: Editei com o codigo completo, eu fechei a tag, porem nao é o erro

Comment: Pedro você está utilizando **mysqli** e não **mysql connection**. O código que demonstrei **não é por mysqli**.

Comment: @mistakeS Mas quando uso o mysql , dá warning avisando que não é mais usado

Answer (score 4):

**1ª Questão, a CRASE:**

```
<?php
    mysqli_connect($conectar, "SELECT * FROM `usuario`");
?>
```

Normalmente ela é utilizada quando querendo referenciar uma tabela ou banco de dados especias, ex:

```
mysql -> CREATE DATABASE `cadastro de alunos`;
mysql -> SELECT `Matrícula` FROM alunos;
```

Então normalmente esse modelo é usado quando queremos acessar ou manipular "nomes" de bancos, tabelas... Isso não se faz e não é recomendado também.

  Um bom e velho "_" resolve tudo, ex:

```
mysql -> CREATE DATABASE cadastro_de_alunos;
mysql -> SELECT * FROM alunos;
```

Não tem porque utilizar "caracteres" especiais.

---

**2º Aspas Simples e Duplas**
**OBS: Até o stackoverflow utiliza essa "regra",** ele não reconhece como String ou Aspas.

> **Não utilize essas aspas "especiais".** 
>   como “” . $escrever[’nome’]

```
 “<tr><td>” . $escrever[’nome’]
 echo “<tr><td>” . $escrever[’nome’] . “</td><td>” . $escrever[’email’] . “</td><td>” . $escrever[’usuario’] . “</td><td>” . $escrever[’nivel_acesso_id’] . “</td></tr>”;
```

> Use as aspas convencionais como **`" código "` (aspas duplas, nesse caso
>   pode ser usado um tratamento html, porém, você terá que da um
>   contra-barra `\"`)** e **`'<img src="imagem.jpg"'` (aspa simples)**,
>   normalmente se usa '' para dar um echo em algum código html, já que os
>   parametros do HTML normalmente são dados a partir de
>   "parametro"**(aspas duplas)**
>
> ---

**3ª Vamos ao código e sem bla bla bla hehehehe!**
  **Seu código:**

```
 <?
              $lista = mysqli_connect($conectar, "SELECT * FROM usuario");
              while($escrever=mysql_fetch_array($lista))
              {
                // Não entendi o porque usar MYSQLI com MYSQL ???

                echo '<tr><td>' . $escrever['nome'] . '</td><td>' . $escrever['email'] . '</td><td>' . $escrever['usuario'] . '</td><td>' . $escrever['nivel_acesso_id'] . '</td></tr>';

              }
                echo '</table>';

               </table>               // Código solto.

                mysql_close(conexao); // mysql_close? Mais você não abriu a conexao com mysqli e mesmo assim, lembre-se $conexao, a chave($).
                // mysql_close é uma funçao entao.
                mysql_close($conexao); // Usando o molde que você criou, não sei de onde vem essa variável, não mostra ela sendo atribída.

            ?>
```

**CRIAÇÃO DO BD para teste:**

```
mysql> create table cadastro (
    -> nome varchar(30) not null,
    -> email varchar(50) not null ) DEFAULT CHARSET utf8;
```

**Código "corrigido":**
 Dei uma dormida para trabalhar melhor isso.
  Cara ta faltando separar a query e são muitas técnicas diferentes. Se liga nisso aqui. Lembrando que a **conexão tem que ser tratada do jeito que tratei aqui**, independente de como você usa.

```
<?php

        // Criei esse modelo para ter uma conexao qualquer.
        $conexao = @mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        mysql_select_db("cadastro"); // Criei e conectei num BD que criei


        // Separa a query na variavel $lista
        $lista = mysql_query("SELECT * from cadastro");
        // Enquanto $escrever != null retorna para $escrever em modo de Array cada linha. 
        while($escrever=mysql_fetch_array($lista))
        {
            echo '<tr><td>' . $escrever["nome"] . '</td><td>' . $escrever["email"] . '</td></tr>'; 
        }

        // Fechando a conexao
        mysql_close($conexao); 
?>
```

> Espero ter clareado ai e também ajudado hehehe, foi textão. Realmente não sei porque utilizar **mysqli** junto com **mysql**, então tratei tudo direto com mysql. **(Pesquise por **PDO**, mysql já não é "mais usado")**.

Com tudo configurado o final é: [image: código funcionando.]

Comment: Entao, fiz o que você falou, agora ta dando outros dois erros diferentes, veja só: Warning: mysqli_connect() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in C:\wamp64\www\painel_prefeitura\lista_user.php on line 78


E o outro erro:

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\wamp64\www\painel_prefeitura\lista_user.php on line 79

Comment: Erro meu, ontem de madrugada não estava com tempo de "ler" e procurar problemas no código. Enfim amigo, atualizei, agora veja e me diga se entendeu e se te ajudou. Abraços e bons desenvolvimentos irmão!

E desculpe pela "preguiça" ontem, realmente estava muito atarefado.

Comment: Copiei idêntico ao seu. E não funciona. Incrível! Tô quase desistindo

Answer (score 2):

Para teu código funcionar vamos fazer algumas alterações. Mas primeiro vamos a teoria.

Você está utilizando a forma procedural do `mysql_query` e está pulando algumas etapas. Caso queira saber mais, existe a forma orientado a objetos do `mysqli_query`. Abordei as diferenças de como utilizá-los [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220978/banco-de-dados-n%C3%A3o-funciona/220997#220997).

Eu percebi que você está chamado a conexão do banco de outro arquivo. Perfeito. Centraliza a conexão ao banco em apenas um lugar do seu projeto e evita retrabalhos.

```
include "conexao.php";
```

Como você não postou nada de como está sendo feito a conexão, vou colocar como é feito na forma orientado a objetos: (Não que o seu esteja errado)

```
// Conecta ao banco de dados
$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'ususario', 'senha', 'banco');
```

Dica: após conectar o banco verifique se não houve erros:

```
/* valida conexão ao banco */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Falha na conexão ao banco: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

Para realizar uma consulta com base em uma `query` você pode fazer assim:

```
// Monta e executa uma consulta SQL
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `usuario` LIMIT 5";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

Para percorrer a consulta você pode fazer usando um laço de repetição, exatamente como está fazendo:

```
// Para cada resultado encontrado...
while ($usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    // Exibe um link com a notícia
    echo $usuario['nome'] . ' - ' . $usuario['email'];
    echo '<br/>';
} // fim while
```

Repare que no array `$usuario['nome']` é aspas simples (`''`), ao invés de crases (``).

E uma dica para exibir o total de linhas vindas na consulta

```
// Total de notícias
echo 'Total de notícias: ' . mysqli_num_rows($query);
```

Qualquer dúvida basta comentar.

Comment: Pq na hora de printar o nome você usou [] e na hora de printar email você usou ()?

Comment: Foi só uma formatação para facilitar a visualização ao aplicar um `var_dump`. Vou retirar

Comment: Heheheheh, entrei a pouco tempo no stack e bom ver que tem muitas pessoas que ajudam. Reescrevi tudo aqui e só percebi que você tinha postado a solução agora. Eu fui mais "explicativo", mas do jeito que você colocou pelo jeito é mais a explanação para a resposta. Obrigado e desculpa irmão! Muito bom o conteúdo.

Comment: Djalma Manfrin, no seu código ta dando o seguinte erro quando eu implemento:  Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given

Comment: Amanhã no trabalho irei verificar o porque do erro

Comment: @Pedro Ribeiro, alterei a reposta para sua necessidade. Não consegui realizar o teste da forma procedural porque gerava o aviso _Please, do not use the mysql extension for new developments._ Por este movito optei por alterar a resposta para forma orientada a objetos. Fiz o teste e funcionou perfeitramente

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o erro esteja nesse trecho, verifique:

```
echo “</table>”;
</table>                 <----------------------------
mysql_close(conexao);
```

Além disso, troque `“` e `”` por `"` ou `'`

Código corrigido:

```
<?php
session_start();
include "seguranca.php";
include "conexao.php";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="Painel Administrativo">
    <meta name="author" content="Prisma Design">
    <link rel="icon" href="imagens/favicon.ico">

    <title>Painel Administrativo</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="administrativo.php">Painel Administrativo 0.1 BETA</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Painel</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Configurações</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Perfil</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ajuda</a></li>
          </ul>
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Procurar...">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
          <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
            <li><a href="administrativo.php">Vista geral</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Suporte</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
            <li><a href="adiciona_user.php">Adicionar usuário</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="lista_user.php">Listar usuários <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
            <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
          <h3 class="page-header"><?php echo "Bem vindo:  ".$_SESSION['usuarioNome']; ?></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
          <table class="table table-hover">
            <tr>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>E-mail</th>
            <th>Usuário</th>
            <th>Nível</th>
            </tr>
            <?
              $lista = mysqli_connect($conectar, "SELECT * FROM `usuario`");
              while($escrever=mysql_fetch_array($lista)){
                echo "<tr><td>" . $escrever[’nome’] . "</td><td>" . $escrever[’email’] . "</td><td>" .
                $escrever[’usuario’] . "</td><td>" . $escrever[’nivel_acesso_id’] . "</td></tr>";

              }
                mysql_close(conexao);

            ?>
            </table>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: o erro persiste

Comment: Verifique agora

Comment: Só uma sugestão Pedro : quando se faz isso : SELECT * FROM usuario você efetua a seleção sobre todos os campos da tabela o ideal para perfomance é isso : "SELECT  nome,email,usuario,nivel_acesso_id FROM usuario. Nome de tabela e campos não é usado entre aspas apenas quando é um texto (string). na sua querie o nome da tabela ficou assim `usuario` retire estas aspas. Abraços....

Comment: O seu tá dando os seguintes erro: Warning: mysqli_connect() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in C:\wamp64\www\painel_prefeitura\lista_user.php on line 78


( ! ) Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\wamp64\www\painel_prefeitura\lista_user.php on line 79
Call St

( ! ) Notice: Use of undefined constant conexao - assumed 'conexao' in C:\wamp64\www\painel_prefeitura\lista_user.php on line 84

( ! ) Warning: mysql_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C:\wamp64\www\painel_prefeitura\lista_user.php on line 84

Comment: Dei atenção ao erro de sintaxe PHP, nem cheguei a reparar no MySQL, creio que esse problema você resolve com a resposta do Djalma