# PHP erro ao exibir resultado de busca com select

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Erro ao selecionar dados do banco de dados.

```
$rs = $conexao->query("SELECT FROM cadastro WHERE ID_Cliente = '83'");

$row = $rs->fetch_assoc();
echo $row['nome'];
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc()
>   on boolean in

Comment: @Inkeliz Não tem nada duplicado. Só tem um registro no BD.

Comment: É exatamente a mesma questão. Sua query está errada, o `SELECT` está vazio, logo retorna `false` e você quer fazer `false->fetch_assoc()`... Mude para `SELECT *`, por exemplo. É exatamente a resposta do @rray "Ao se deparar com o erro acima, significa que sua consulta falhou, para saber a origem do erro". Se isso não é duplicado...

Comment: @Inkeliz Verdade. puts, esqueci desse detalhe bobo... kkkk

Answer (score 0):

Referente a sua dúvida sobre `mysql` e `mysqli`. Primeiramente é importante saber que a forma `mysql` trabalha da forma procedural e `mysqli` da forma orientado a objetos. [Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220978/banco-de-dados-n%C3%A3o-funciona/220997#220997) você encontra como trabalhar das duas formas.

O erro acontece por que sua consulta está trazendo `false`.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in

O correto é fazer uma validação

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `usuario` LIMIT 5";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if ($query) {
    // Pode fazer assim
    while ($usuario = mysqli_fetch_object($query)) {
        // Exibe um link com a notícia
        echo $usuario->nome . ' - ' . $usuario->email;
        echo '<br/>';
    }
}
```